# Google CEL query (dynamic groups) on custom schemas

Tags: schema, google-workspace

I'm trying to create a CEL query for a Google dynamic group to match a custom attribute defined in customSchemas. It's defined that way (looking at it via gam) :

```
Schema: EmployeeType
 schemaId: xxx
 displayName: EmployeeType
 Field: UserType
  fieldId: _xxx
  fieldType: STRING
  displayName: UserType
  multiValued: False
  readAccessType: ADMINS_AND_SELF
  indexed: True
```

which, when looking at the user's info, is mapped this way : `customSchemas.EmployeeType.UserType`

My issue is that I can't seem to build a query to return users for a given `UserType` value. I tried the following :

```
user.EmployeeType.exists(x x.UserType=='MyValue')
user.customSchemas.EmployeeType.exists(x x.UserType=='MyValue')
user.customSchemas.exists(x x.EmployeeType.UserType=='MyValue')
```

Nothing is working. I think dynamic groups might not handle custom attributes, but I could also just have the wrong query. Can someone shed some light on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, custom attributes are not valid attributes for dynamic groups CEL query, see https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/dynamic-groups-attributes?hl=en

Moreover, I've been trying to build CEL queries for dynamic groups, expanding on the graphical query builder in the admin console and reading the CEL spec. I can confirm that only queries that can be built via the graphical query builder will be validated for dynamic group queries. Builiding a valid CEL query that isn't offered by the graphical query builder (such as using startsWitch, endsWith, matches()) does not work, whether via the web interface or the API. Hopefully Google changes that.

Comment: there is currently no solution (but managing attributes differently)